# HashiCorp Vault auto unsealed with Azure Vault - still shows - Recovery Seal Type as shamir

Tags: azure, azure-aks, hashicorp-vault

Have installed Vault on Azure Kubernetes and have configured the auto unseal with Azure Key vault.
Initially post the deployment , Vault status returns with Seal type as "azurekeyvault" and sealed as true.
Once I have initiated with below command.

`kubectl exec -it hashivault-0 -n vault -- vault operator init -recovery-shares=1 -recovery-threshold=1`

Post that Seal type is changed as "shamir" but the Vault is accessible and active.

Is this expected behavior or is it not referring to Azure Key vault certificates for unsealing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Official Document of Hashicorp , It seems to be expected behavior .

When you seal your vault's status will be `Recovery Seal Type : azurekeyvault` and `Sealed : true` But after the vault operator is initialized the vault's status will be `Recovery Seal Type : shamir` and `sealed : false` as per auto-unseal feature.

**Reference:**

[Auto-unseal using Azure Key Vault | Vault - HashiCorp Learn](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/autounseal-azure-keyvault?in=vault/auto-unseal#step-2-test-the-auto-unseal-feature)